# Error when running php script from bash script via php exec()

Tags: php, macos, mamp, mamp-pro

I am on a MAC Montery with MAMP PRO trying to run a bash script using exec().  This bash script in turn calls another php script.  My files are below.

**import.php**

```
exec('import.sh 2>&1', $output, $result_code);
```

**import.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PHP=`which php`
$PHP phpscript.php 2>&1
```

**phpscript.php**

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// do stuff
?>
```

**~/.bash_profile**

```
source ~/.profile
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH"
```

**~/.profile**

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin:${PATH}"
alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/php -c "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php7.4.21.ini"'
alias composer='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/composer'
alias php-config='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/php-config'
alias phpdbg='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/phpdbg'
alias phpize='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/phpize'
alias pear='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/pear'
alias peardev='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/peardev'
alias pecl='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/pecl'
```

When I run this code, I get the following error returned to the browser...

**env: php: No such file or directory**

My path is okay I think and I told MAMP to add the aliases in the ~/.profile.

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

Any ideas as to why **#!/usr/bin/env php** isn't finding the php under MAMP?

I realize that MAC just removed native PHP support, but I don't know why env isn't finding PHP that is provided by MAMP.

Comment: You need quotes around `import.sh 2>&1`

Comment: Put `$()` or backticks around `which php`, not single quotes.

Comment: Sorry, I do have quotes.  It is a string.  I didn't copy it directly because it is really long path to the sh file.  also, I do have backtics around which php.  I fixed it.  Thanks.  Still have the error.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `which php`? Just use `php phpscript.php`. They both search `$PATH`.

Comment: In my import.sh file, if I use just `php phpscript.php`, I get this error... `import.sh: line 26: php: command not found`

Comment: `which`, `env`, and using the `php` command directly all use the same method to find the program. So they'll all either succeed or fail for the same reason.

Comment: How are you running `import.php`? If you're running it from MAMP, that doesn't run your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Yeah, which is strange.  For some reason php and env php are failing, and I don't know what is going on.  It's like MAMP exec() isn't working right or something.

Comment: import.php is just a standard php web page that calls exec('import.sh 2>&1', $output, $result_code);

Comment: That's what I was trying to say. Web pages don't run your personal `.profile`. So your change to `PATH` has no effect there.

Comment: oh sorry.  I see.  So I need to use putenv also, right?

Comment: Nothing you do in your account has any effect on how web pages run.

Comment: You could put a link to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/php` in `/usr/bin`, then it will be found by everyone.

Comment: Okay I see.  Let me try to call putenv() in import.php first and then make the exec() call and see if that works.  Thanks for the help.